# ios coreplot setup

Tags: ios, core-plot

It was difficult to get `CorePlot` to work in my project, but everything runs now. I just don't see ANYTHING other than a blank white screen.

With the following code, shouldn't I at least so a blank graph?

```
self.graph = [[[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
layerHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

[self addSubview:layerHostingView];
```

***Thanks*** for *helping* me with this.

*FYI* this is not my first test with `coreplot`. I've been spinning my wheels on this for days and have since tried every full example I can get my hands on. I figured it's a good idea to start over again with the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in the code you posted in your answer, you created a `CPTGraphHostingView` and added it as a subview of the `RaceDetailView`. In the code in your question, I suspect the hosting view was nil. I don't think adding the theme would make a difference--the default appearance is a simple white background with black lines and labels and you'd still be able to see something.

Comment: I honestly don't know the real answer and I'm too uninterested to figure out what it is. However, I feel much better about giving you the answer than giving it to me. Knowing that you'll get more points from it is the greater good!

Answer (score 3):

I honestly have no idea what changed, but I see a *naked* graph with this code.

## .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"

@interface RaceDetailView : UIView <CPTPlotSpaceDelegate, CPTPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate>

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "RaceDetailView.h"

@implementation RaceDetailView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CGRect f = self.frame;
        CPTXYGraph *graph = [[[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:f] autorelease];
        CPTGraphHostingView *layerHostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:f];
        layerHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
        [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];

        [self addSubview:layerHostingView];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```